# ng-class doesnot get evaluated

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

```
<div ng-if="question.type =='options'" ng-repeat="option in question.options" >
   <ion-radio name="{{$parent.question.id}}" 
       ng-model="$parent.question.answer" 
       required ng-value="option.id"  
       ng-class="{'has-custom-error':submitted && questionForm.{{$parent.question.id}}.$invalid,
       'has-custom-success':questionForm.{{$parent.question.id}}.$valid }" 
    >
       {{option.text}}
    </ion-radio>
</div>
```

I have to add has-custom-error on user  submitting the form without selecting the option.That is form is not valid but the ng-classis not getting evaluated.

The demo code is over here:http://plnkr.co/edit/FwjoCTYONvi3BoFHNKFK?p=preview

Comment: have you used an angular inspector to check the values on your objects? if you follow the chain, you'll notice something odd with how  the name of the field is being placed on questionForm... namely you'll notice a property called "{{$parent.question.id}}". also when you are referencing object properties from within expressions, don't use {{}} it's wrong. use questionForm[$parent.question.id], which is correct javascript syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to use {{ }} expressions on a ng-class expression. You should be able to use it like this questionForm[$parent.question.id]

Also I never got ng-class working with classes with - between the parts, only CamelCase like hasCustomError. So {hasCustomError: questionForm.$invalid} should work.

Have you considered using the styleClass ng-invalid-required that is already used by angular for your styling? It is usually a lot cleaner, since there is no need for all the ng-class expressions

Comment: i used ng-invalid-required class but still the answer to my question is not yet solved

Comment: I forked your plunker and changed the css so it response to the invalid state of the field. http://plnkr.co/edit/dQDzf2KPk868jRgg2ghS?p=preview

Comment: It seems you already do this in the plunker, but for clarification, it is possible to use classes that contains `-`, just wrap it with a single quote `ng-class="{'has-custom-error': .. "`

Answer (score 0):

There is at least one problem with your code. You must not use interpolation {{}} within your ng-class attribute. Here is the correct syntax:

```
ng-class="{'has-custom-error':submitted && questionForm[$parent.question.id].$invalid, 'has-custom-success':questionForm[$parent.question.id].$valid }"
```

Comment: I have tried this before also it is not working still.canyou just see plunk and reply why it is so?

Answer (score 0):

When you are inside an Angular expression, you don't need the mustache braces. So your code should be:

```
<div ng-if="question.type =='options'" ng-repeat="option in question.options">
   <ion-radio name="{{$parent.question.id}}" 
              ng-model="$parent.question.answer" 
             required ng-value="option.id"  
             ng-class="{'has-custom-error':submitted && questionForm[$parent.question.id].$invalid,
'has-custom-success':questionForm[$parent.question.id].$valid }">
       {{option.text}}
    </ion-radio>
</div>
```

The variable form a.b has been replaced by the indexer form a["b"] so that it is evaluated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use double-mustached expressions (`{{ ... }}`) inside expressions. The ng-class value is already an expression of type object, so you're supposed to use JavaScript syntax inside this attribute:

```
ng-class="{'has-custom-error': submitted && questionForm[$parent.question.id].$invalid,
           'has-custom-success': questionForm[$parent.question.id].$valid }"
```

The use of `$parent` is also unecessary. BTW, you're not using it for your ng-repeat expression:

```
ng-repeat="option in question.options"
```

So you should simply use `question` instead of `$parent.question`: the scope of the ng-repeat block inherits from its parent scope, and the question is thus available through inheritance.

Note that, playing with your plunkr, it seems like the ion-radio directive that you're using doesn't correctly set the name attribute of the input it generates. This is probably why the CSS classes don't appear.

Comment: ok then i will have to use some other directive for it .And ya i had used questionForm[$parent.question.id] but it was still  not working now i think it is the problem with the directive of ionic.Thanks

Comment: But i am doing samething in textarea tag it is not working still

Answer (score 0):

ng-form is the solution to my problem.But the problem that I am facing is in the name attribute of my `ion-radio` directive. For radio  hence i used angular `ng-invalid-required`.And for other html tag i used `ng-form.$invalid`